# underscorejs - How to remove array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

underscorejs - How to remove array?

I have an array of objects. I would like to remove an array. Please refer my code below for more details,

```
array = [{a:10,b:20},{c:10,b:20},{a:10,d:20}];
```

Expected output: `{a:10,b:20},{c:10,b:20},{a:10,d:20}`

Comment: your question makes no sense. your expected output is not valid javascript. your 'array' var is a list of objects, but your expected output also looks like a list of objects.you can iterate over the objects using javascripts native forEach method - is that what you mean?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? As mentioned above, the expected output will lead you nowhere

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with underscore either? Unless you mean how to make your array an object.

var newObj;
_.each(array,function(object,index){
newObj[index] = object;
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand You need output without []. To manage that first stringify array, next cut first and last letter.

```js
var array = [{a:10,b:20},{c:10,b:20},{a:10,d:20}];
var str=JSON.stringify(array);
console.log(str.substring(1,str.length-1));
```

Final string has no [] signs but this is not valid JSON structure. In JSON must be one root element like [] or {}.